# What is a real world example of "zero work" done by a conservative vector field?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have only a high school physics background, so when I study the later parts of multivariable calculus, e.g., Greens, Gauss, and Stokes' theorems, there are some topics that I only know the mathematics of - but not the physical significance of the theorems.

One question in particular is this:  why does a conservative vector field integrate to zero, on a closed curve?  This is supposed to mean that the vector field did "no work".

What's a good, real world example of this result?  (I don't need a math proof.)

Thanks,

Comment: A satellite stays on its orbit without needing to consume any propellant per lap. It does not lose any speed either (except possibly due to tiny amounts of atmospheric drag on lower orbits).

Comment: Very cool example, @JyrkiLahtonen - thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity! Imagine if you have some object at a height $h$. From some physical intuition, you can imagine that, as long as you get back to the same position (and in fact, you could end up at any point with the height $h$!), there will be no energy gain from the (Newtonian) gravity.

Comment: Hi @KennethGoodenough:  hmm...gravity...I'll sound really silly saying this but, do you mean like dropping an object from a height of h?  Then the object hits the ground position, though, and doesn't return to a height of h (it moved along some curve that started at h and ended at zero, for example.)  So it hasn't moved along a "closed curve" to return to its original position.  What I am thinking incorrectly of?  Thanks,

Comment: @user258314 Amount of work a vector field does may be not only positive, but also negative. If a ball drops and falls down, the gravitational vector field performs positive work that you can get out in terms of energy. After the ball hits the ground, *you* can lift it up back (closing the curve), so that *you* now has to provide energy and the vector field would do negative work. After the object is back to its original position you can see that the amount of positive work of gravity and that of negative work (meaning your positive work) is *the same* in absolute values, that is zero.

Comment: You are right, dropping some object from a height will not return it back to its height, so when it hits the ground, the work will be non-zero, and in fact will be positive. This implies that we can use an object dropping from some height to gain some energy, for example.

However, if we would try to move the object back to the same height (by hand or any other physical method) to try to gain energy again, we see that that will never be of any benefit, since the work will be zero again.

Comment: Awesome, at A.G. :-)  based on what you described, can we consider all holomorphic functions on a simply connected domain to be "conservative" too (by the Cauchy Goursat theorem)?  Even though the objects are different - in the real variables case we are looking at vector-valued functions, in the complex setting, we are looking at one-variable complex-valued functions.  But complex-valued functions also integrate to zero, just exactly as you described.

Comment: Ok, got it @KennethGoodenough - thanks so much!

Comment: @user258314 You are right. The Cauchy formula for a holomorphic function $f=u+iv$ is *exactly* the Green formula for the vector field $(u,-v)$ (the last one has zero curl due to the Cauchy-Riemann condition).

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @A.G.!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The most common, simple examples of conservative vector fields are the gravitational and electronic fields around a point particle. These are conservative fields, so the concept of "potential energy" of gravitation or static electricity makes sense. This also allows orbits, as @JyrkiLahtonen just pointed out in a commment. (Remember that for a while, electrons were though to orbit the nucleus).

The point particles are the simplest, but of course the fields can be generalized to uniform spherical objects, spherical objects where the density depends only on the distance from the center, and so on.

@KennethGoodenough brought up a simplification, where the field is uniform. I suppose that would be the simplest of all.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RoryDaulton!